# Enzyme and Google map CDN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to test with Enzyme a component which is using the CDN of Google map as you can see below:

```
/* global google */
import React from 'react';

class GoogleMap extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    /* eslint-disable no-new */
    new google.maps.Map(this.map, {
      center: { lat: 45.772141, lng: 4.874891 },
      zoom: 16,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={(c) => { this.map = c; }}
        style={{ width: 500, height: 300 }}
      >I should be a map!
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleMap;
```

As I expected, this test below:

```
describe('GoogleMap', () => {
  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(GoogleMap).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should render correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<GoogleMap />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Got me this error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Map' of undefined

       5 |   componentDidMount() {
       6 |     /* eslint-disable no-new */
    >  7 |     new google.maps.Map(this.map, {
       8 |       center: { lat: 45.772141, lng: 4.874891 },
       9 |       zoom: 16,
      10 |     });
```

Anyone can help me do fix this error? Or have I to escape the GoogleMap test? And more generally can we test with enzyme some CDN?

Comment: `GoogleMap` is your own component that should be tested, so don't skip it, but a third-party library could be mocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Or B thank you, I have search about the third-party library and I have found an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/955) about the google undefined that I haven't found before.

The code below don't mock the third library but, I think if I have understand, declare to jest a new empty class which will permit to don't throw an error.

```
//setupTests.js
google = {
  maps: {
    Map: class {}
  }
};
```